# changed comments in c program and its resulting in segmentatoin fault

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, clang, gnu-make

this the difference between commits, which is just different comments and line spaces, but the old commit runs normally and the new result in a seg fault:

```c
Binary files a/recover/recover and b/recover/recover differ
diff --git a/recover/recover.c b/recover/recover.c
index f0ffdf6..02ab42b 100644
--- a/recover/recover.c
+++ b/recover/recover.c
@@ -1,34 +1,32 @@
-#include <stdint.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
+#include <stdint.h>
 #include <string.h>
 
 typedef enum
 {
-   false,
-   true
-} bool;
+   true,
+   false
 
-typedef uint8_t BYTE;
+} bool;
 
 typedef char *string;
 
+typedef uint8_t BYTE;
 int BLOCK_SIZE = 512;
 
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
-   // Check if a file name was provided as an argument
-   if (argc < 2)
+   if (argc != 2)
    {
-      fprintf(stderr, "Error: No file name provided.\n");
+      fprintf(stderr, "Usage: recover {filename}\n");
       return 1;
    }
-
-   // Open the file for reading
-   FILE *raw_file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
+   string fpath = argv[1] == NULL ? "./card.raw" : argv[1];
+   FILE *raw_file = fopen(fpath, "r");
    if (raw_file == NULL)
    {
-      fprintf(stderr, "Error: Could not open file.\n");
+      fprintf(stderr, "Error: filename not valid!\n");
       return 2;
    }
 
@@ -38,33 +36,31 @@ int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    FILE *img = NULL;
    bool opened = false;
 
-   // Read blocks of size BLOCK_SIZE from the file
    while (fread(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, raw_file) == BLOCK_SIZE)
    {
-      // If start of new JPEG
+      // if start of new jpeg
       if (buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
       {
-         // If a JPEG file is already open, close it and free the filename
+         // if opened
          if (opened)
          {
             free(fname);
             fclose(img);
          }
-         // Allocate memory for the new filename and create a new JPEG file
+         // opened or not
          fname = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
          sprintf(fname, "%03i.jpg", i);
          img = fopen(fname, "w");
          opened = true;
          i++;
       }
-      // If a JPEG file is open, write the block to it
+      // if opened jpeg start or not
       if (opened)
       {
          fwrite(buffer, 1, BLOCK_SIZE, img);
       }
    }
-
-   // If a JPEG file is open, close it and free the filename
+   // when gone over entire disk image
    if (opened)
    {
       free(fname);
```

It's basically the same program just different formatting and comments, it doesn't make sense at all.
I don't any difference or error in the code, if you can, please share with us!

expected: running normally
got: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Run Valgrind on it.

Comment: `typedef char *string;`!?!?!  Ooooh my eyes!  Where's the eye bleach!?!?  Hiding a pointer behind a `typedef` is a **REALLY** bad idea that only causes confusion - and bugs.

Comment: It's most likely a school assignment.  Some C classes use this typedef to hide the char* pointers.  I'm not personally a fan, because C students really need to know how to do this idiomatically.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - re hiding pointers - I wonder if this is a cs50 influance.

Comment: "It's basically the same program just different formatting and comments" hmm... I see several real code changes...

Comment: Given the `typedef` for `string`, the following two lines are a problem:  `string fpath = argv[1] == NULL ? "./card.raw" : argv[1];
  FILE *raw_file = fopen(fpath, "r");`

Comment: Moral of this story: if you touch something and it breaks... perhaps you broke it? (Alternately: “Pray, Mr. Babbage...”) A good software engineer/programmer/whatever will not blame his tools for his mistakes.

Comment: @AndrewHenle — the CS50 course both uses `typedef char *string;` and has an exercise that involves recovering image data from files.  I think the OP included the definitions here rather than using `#include <cs50.h>` and adding the [tag:cs50] tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement “It's basically the same program just different formatting and comments” is ludicrous. The commit changes:

```
   false,
   true
```

to:

```
   true,
   false
```

with the result that the values for `false` and `true` of 0 and 1, respectively, are changed to 1 and 0, respectively.

The code declares `opened` to be `bool` and uses it in `if (opened)`. This obviously uses the wrong sense for `opened`.

Comment: And there are more.  `if (argc < 2)` becomes `if (argc != 2)` and so on.

Comment: Also note that standard C has a built-in type `_Bool` and `#include <stdbool.h>` defines `true` and `false` and `bool`.  Those should be used rather than homebrew definitions.  In C23, those are promoted to full keywords and the header becomes obsolete.

Comment: so if i'm using an enum i should be verbosely check for its value, thanks.